# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout to view

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-support-design

I want to inflate the layout below, but it gives me an error.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
      ....
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i try this code that give me error

```
 LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.fooview, null, false)
```

I will have set

1) `AppTheme.NoActionBar` style of `activity`

2) `'com.android.support:design:26.+'`  dependencies added

3)  and `Activity` was extends by `AppCompatActivity`

error in log

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: What error ? Its a runtime error ?

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: what is line no `14`

Comment: that was <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: extends `AppCompatActivity `

Comment: i have set AppCompatActivity to MainActivity but it can give error

Comment: can you add your full xml

Comment: sorry for that but i can not add this

Answer (score 0):

Created sample for you. It's work for me hope it's help full to you

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private TextView sampleText;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_two,null,false);
        sampleText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        sampleText.setText("Hello Code Sample");
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Code Sample"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For me no errors. You have to add dependencies.

Comment: i have use for Fragment it work well. you are right but when i try inflater in activity that time give error

Answer (score 0):

With Activity :

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout linearLy;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private TextView txtTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        linearLy = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLy);
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_two, null, false);
        txtTextView = (TextView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txtTextView.setText("Hello Sample");
        linearLy.addView(coordinatorLayout);
    }

}
```

MainLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLy"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Inflated activity_sample_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Code Sample"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Let me know if require more help!

Comment: i think the error was there LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())

Comment: You can try "this" instated of "getApplicationContext() "
 
e.g. LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.fooview, null, false)